# How to update the custom value in a view model object

Tags: android, dao, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to create a menu setting that will update the value passed into a ViewModelFactory and return a new list of that size.

I've tried passing the value and calling ViewModelFactory again, but the list size doesn't update.

```
    factory = new WordViewModelFactory(getApplication(), listSize);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(WordViewModel.class);

    ((WordViewModel) viewModel).getWordList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Word>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Word> words) {
           Log.d("Shawn", words.toString());
            rvadapter.setWord(words);
        }
    });
```

Menu selection

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_display_3:
                menuSelection(3);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_display_5:
                menuSelection(5);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_object_info:
                Log.d("Shawn", viewModel.toString());
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void menuSelection(int listSize) {
        Log.d("Shawn", "menuSelection num = " + listSize);

    }
```

ViewModel

```
    private Repository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Word>> wordList;

    public WordViewModel(Application application, int listSize) {
        super(application);
        repository = new Repository(application, listSize);
        wordList = repository.getWordList();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Word>> getWordList() {
        return wordList;
    }

    public LiveData<List<Word>> updateList(int newListSize) {

        return wordList.postValue(newListSize);
    }
```

Repository

```
    private Repository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Word>> wordList;


    public WordViewModel(Application application, int listSize) {
        super(application);
        repository = new Repository(application, listSize);
        wordList = repository.getWordList();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Word>> getWordList() {
        return wordList;
    }
```

DAO

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table ORDER BY word ASC LIMIT :size")
    LiveData<List<Word>> getAllNotes(int size);
```

Comment: what menu setting are you talking about? have you `observe` the data in your `viewmodel`? you can post parts of your code here

Comment: @Wesely I've added the code to where I've gotten to but don't know how I should be update my List size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call viewModelFactory again. To update the value in `WordViewModel` you need to create a setter in viewModel and update the LiveData.

Add this function into your WordViewModel

```
public void setWordList(Application application, int listSize) {
    repository = new Repository(application, listSize);
    wordList = repository.getWordList();
}
```

(note: At each time you call the above function it will create object of repository, It is a bad way you need to change the structure)

And call this function from activity/fragment like given below

```
((WordViewModel) viewModel).setWordList(application, listSize)
```

Comment: This ended up working for perfect for me thanks @Niyas for helping me get there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `ViewModel` concept is not `setter`, it's more like `update`

You've already `Observed` your `ViewModel.getWordList()` in your `View`, that's correct.

Since the `wordList` is a `LiveData`, you use

```
wordList.postValue(newValue)
```

to let all the observers know it got a new update.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and the concept behind **postValue(newValue)**, but I'm lost on how to add this to wordList, do I need to make the wordList in the ViewModel public?

Comment: you can do that by providing a method like `viewModel.updateList(newList)`, I think that's better than just go public.

Comment: @Wesley, I created an updated method in the ViewModel but the ** wordList** doesn't recognize the **postValue(newValue)**. I'll post it in the ViewModel section of this question.

'postValue(java.util.List<com.example.viewmodelfactoryactivity.Word>)' has protected access in 'android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData'

Comment: you should use  `MutableLiveData` if its value will be changed